# Where to find stored data with local storage (Ionic2) on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, local-storage

I developed an application for Android with **Ionic2** framework. I used **Local storage** functions to handle data.
Now, I want to replace local storage by database with some API calls.
And before switching to my API, I wish to extract the application data in order to no lost them.

**Q1**: That why, I wonder where is the **path** for the local storage data? In other words, where can I find the file with my stored data?

**Q2**: If retrieving my data isn't possible. I was wondering: If I modify the application with a **extract** function, when I reinstall it, will it delete my data or leave it as it is? (and so extract my data easily)

Thanks for your help!
I hope I gave enough information.

Local storage doc: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage/

Which use localForage: https://github.com/localForage/localForage

Comment: If you tried running your project with ionic serve and it appeared in Chrome say, use right click ->inspect -> Application tab -> Storage section. -> IndexedDB -> Refresh database. From thereabouts you've find your data. Often there are things like a a refresh icon at top/bottom of a results tab.

Comment: If the info is on someones device already, you might find a way to add a service that emailed JSON to something that would convert it into a persistent storage.